# how to debug play framework 2.5 in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, debugging, playframework, typesafe-activator, playframework-2.5

Enviroment 
OS : OS X EL Capitan
IDE: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Activator : activator-dist-1.3.10. 
My step. 
--> But at the last step,  I can't connect to vm. Wating  for vm connect at port 999.
Please help me !
[image: Run server]

[image: Run project]

[image: Debug setting]

[image: But long time to connect to VM]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your debug configuration you have to set `Connection Type` to `Standard (Socket Attach)` (in the screenshot you have selected `Standard (Socket Listen)`.

Comment: I have just selected  Standard (Socket Listen) but after that have a message "No operations to display at this time." at Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

open your eclipse
Navigate to Help->eclipsemarketplace
Search scala
Then install two plugins:-
1) ScalaStyle 0.7.0
2) Scala Ide 4.2.x
run below command in console from your project directory
Note: before debug first run this command
 
activator -jvm-debug 9999 run
now right click on project
go to 
Debug as -> debug configuration click new and insert project name
set port number to 9999
now select **Scala debugger(socket attach)**(Scala debugger will come only if you have installed those plugin mentioned above) from dropdown 
and click on debug